# Why my csv file comes blank when I use this python code? can not get data from indeed

Tags: python

I'm going to scrape job site the I have face some problem like when I scrape data from indeed website and save it to csv file. My csv file comes blank can some one correct me? whole code is below....

the whole code is below.. this link has the whole code..
https://github.com/Ram-95/Indeed_Job_Scraper/blob/master/Indeed_Job_Scraper.py

```
         # Scrapping the Web
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    base_url = 'https://in.indeed.com/viewjob?jk='
    d = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'mosaic-provider-jobcards'})

    jobs = soup.find_all('a', class_='tapItem')

    for job in jobs:
        job_id = job['id'].split('_')[-1]
        job_title = job.find('span', title=True).text.strip()
        company = job.find('span', class_='companyName').text.strip()
        location = job.find('div', class_='companyLocation').text.strip()
        posted = job.find('span', class_='date').text.strip()
        job_link = base_url + job_id
        #print([job_title, company, location, posted, job_link])

        # Writing to CSV File
        writer.writerow(
            [job_title, company, location.title(), posted, job_link])
```

print(f'Jobs data written to <{file_name}> successfully.')

Comment: you have not used opencv anywhere

Comment: I've removed those tags that have nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with the `csv` module failing to write the file, it is with your scraping script failing to scrape anything. There are a number of errors in your code. First, in line 45, you assign the result of a `soup.find` to a variable `d`, then proceed to completely ignore that variable. I'm assuming you wanted to use it in the next line:

```
jobs = d.find_all('div', class_='tapItem')
```

Secondly, since you are using the lxml parser, your won't get anything for `job['id']`. Try this instead:

```
job_id = job.attrs['class'][4]
```

So your code should essentially look like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
base_url = 'https://in.indeed.com/viewjob?jk='
d = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'mosaic-provider-jobcards'})
jobs = d.find_all('div', class_='tapItem')

for job in jobs:
    job_id = job.attrs['class'][4]
    job_title = job.find('span', title=True).text.strip()
    company = job.find('span', class_='companyName').text.strip()
    location = job.find('div', class_='companyLocation').text.strip()
    posted = job.find('span', class_='date').text.strip()
    job_link = base_url + job_id
    #print([job_title, company, location, posted, job_link])
    #Writing to CSV File
    
    writer.writerow(
            [job_title, company, location.title(), posted, job_link])
```

Comment: it's not "OpenCSV", it's "OpenCV", and that still has nothing to do with the problem. OP mistagged his post. he's using python's built-in `csv` module for writing.

Comment: after adding your suggestion I have found this problem https://prnt.sc/HJ7Jk9tPhQ6g


AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: @mdsun Yes obviously if there are no results from the search, you wouldn't get anything: https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=Manager&l=New%20York,%20NY